# Confluent Schema Registry "subjects" and "versions"

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am learning about Confluent's Schema Registry for all Schema management needs.

And I do not quite understand their approach to versioning... 
There is a notion of a `subject`, which I see as a namespace. As far as I understand subject must be unique across Schema Registry.

Then there is schema id, or just `id`, which is also unique.

And, finally, there is a `version`.

Here is the snippet from documentation:

> `version`: the schema version for this subject, which starts at 1 for
>   each subject
>
> `id`: the globally unique schema version id, unique across
>   all schemas in all subjects

So, once I want to modify a schema under a particular subject, what happens to `id` and `version` fields? Does `id` change? Does the `version` get incremented?

Another quote:

> When schemas evolve, they are still associated to the same subject but get a new schema ID and version

Does every change warrant a new `id` and a new `version`?

Answer (score 2):

Every subject has a list of versions. You can verify this in the source code, if you wish.

Every id in the Registry is globally unique, not ids within the "list of subject versions". There's only an incremental number of versions, per subject, stored based on the compatibility mode of the registry and this is an index, not a proper ID.

If two subjects share the same schema, the schema ID is **the same**, although the "version index" within two different subjects could be different. See example below for this case.

Every unique schema (as defined by it's textual representation) has a unique (possibly incremental) ID. They are MD5-hashed, or "fingerprinted" for uniqueness, then globally compared to one another across a Schema Registry cluster. This is done with the equivalent of `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Schema>` where the key is the hash of the value `Schema` object

---

example: Use `sub`, `v`, and `s` for subject, version and schema

1. Create sub<sub>1</sub>, that makes v<sub>1</sub>:s<sub>1</sub>
2. Update it to create v<sub>2</sub>:s<sub>2</sub>
3. Take that updated schema text and POST it to a new sub<sub>2</sub>

sub<sub>1</sub> : [ v<sub>1</sub>:s<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>:s<sub>2</sub> ]
sub<sub>2</sub> : [ v<sub>1</sub>:s<sub>2</sub> ]

Regarding the question

> want to modify a schema under a particular subject, what happens to id and version fields? Does id change? Does the version get incremented?

The version will always be incremented if you make a compatible schema change. If your edit to the subject schema happens to match some other subject schema definition, then the ID wouldn't change

Comment: Not sure I understand. Let's drop the subject for a second. Say I post a schema, it is being assigned a schemaId and a version, then I make a change to that schema, I update it. Do I get a new schema id and a new version as a result of update?

Comment: Yup! The schema would be different. Thus a new id. If you post to the same subject, then you also get a new version. If you post the new schema to a new subject, you then have at least 2 schemas, each with at least 1 verison.

Comment: This is as clear as mud. Why it has to be so confusing? 
Why are you saying that "use schema to create subject"? 
Cannot I create subject first as a step one and then to that subject I'll associate my schema(s).
 
What is the cardinality here? 
Confluent's documentation around SchemaRegistry is not the best to say the least.

Comment: You HTTP `POST` a schema to a subject. You cannot do one without the other. When you do that, it creates either version 1, or the next version. The cardinality is N `SchemaVersion` objects to 1 `Subject`, represented internally as `Map<String, List<SchemaVerison>>`

Comment: It is pretty clear, the subject to version cardinality, what I do not understand why schema id also changes.

Comment: in your example, step #3 you say: "take the same schema and use it to create sub2" and as a result you get sub2 : [ v1:s2 ]. But we have already established that "same schema" is at [v2:s2]

Comment: what is the point of evolving both at the same time schema id and version? 
I understand if every change to the schema with a given id is upversioning to a new version. But why is there a need to also issue a new schema id?

Comment: Schema ID changes because all schemas are unique. Do you not understand what hashing means? `v2:s2` exists because you took the same exact schema (at subject1) and added to subject2. This would cause the creation of a version list, and the schema text is hashed *the exact same* to check for uniqueness and compared to all other schema hashes already in the registry. Since it matches schema2, as said, then it is subject2->version1->schema2. The scope of schema IDs are global. The subject version scope is not.

Comment: You should add this last comment to your answer, without it your original answer is not complete.
I had no idea how it works behind the scenes. Please do not assume that it is obvious, b/c it is not.
Thanks for your help in this matter!

Comment: @Rick I don't work for Confluent. If you have a problem with their product, talk to someone who does